# Excel Formula with IF... ELSE

Tags: excel, formula

[image]

Hi all,

I have this excel where by I need to find the location of the item if they are found in column B.

So In my F column, I tried to write ifelse formula which didnt work.which is

```
=IF(D2="NULL","NONE",C((D2))).
```

My idea is if D2 is not null, use the value in D column to find the location in C column. In this example, fish no 4, so it is found, my F column should show the value "C" using the value shown in D column and use it as Row no in C column

I hope you guys get the idea and help me out a newbie in excel. Thanks in advance

Comment: and what do you want to have happen if its NULL in D?

Answer (score 0):

[edit]to pull proper location column, not just the row #[/edit]

Seems like a job for `MATCH`+`OFFSET`

Try this formula in cell F2:

`=OFFSET($C$1, MATCH(E2,B:B,0)-1, 0, 1, 1)`

Match is used to locate the value in the first argument (ie E2) within the range specified in 2nd argument (ie B:B).  I use B:B but you could also use range `B2:B30` or whatever more specific range you want. (I prefer the more generic B:B, though :) )

Third paramter "0" just indicates "Exact match". 
This function will retun "#N/A" if nothing found.

OFFSET takes the result from MATCH to pick out the Location you want. The first parameter in OFFSET is the rows below (or above if negative) from the base row (in this case $C$1). the next is the column: 0 since we're in the column we want to be in. The last two are the size of the range: 1,1 is a 1x1 cell, so just 1 cell. If we did ...,2,3), that would be 2 rows high and 3 columns wide - or a 6 cell range. We're just after 1 cell here.

I've always preferred MATCH + OFFSET to other options, I just found they held up more robustly to changes in a sheet (ie new rows/columns added). So it's mostly personaly preference over VLOOKUP and INDEX.  I honestly have never compared their actual performance, however, I've never had any issues with MATCH+OFFSET running slowly :)

Comment: I think you need to combine your match with an INDEX

Comment: Why ?  Match returns the # offset that is found, which seems to be what the OP is asking for, ie "I need to find the location of the item" ... no need to do anything more .. Match gives him what he's asking for

Comment: yes, but you are thinking of location as in row number or index number for the position in the column, the OP is talking about location as in A, B, C, F or G.  In the end of the second last paragraph OP even states the outcome desired " my F column should show the value "C" "  Match on its own wont return a Value of "C".

Comment: DOH!  You're absolutely correct, sorry, my bad. I missed that :(  Yeah, need an extra lookup on that. I'll update my answer. Thank-you!

Comment: actually there is another good reason to use INDEX over OFFSET.  Offset is a volatile function meaning that it will recalculate anytime something changes on the work sheet.  So if there are a lot of offsets on the sheet it can bog things down.  INDEX is not volatile, so it will only recalculate when something it refers to changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
=vlookup($D2,$A$2:$C$6,3,0)
```

you can use that in column F.  Place that formula in F2 and copy down.

you could technically use it in column E as well, but you would need to change the 3 to a 2.

you did not say what you wanted to do if the D value was "Null" so I am going to take a stab at the dark and wrap you lookup formula in an if statement that will deal with "Null" or empty cells

```
=IF(OR($D2="NULL",$D2=""),"",VLOOKUP($D2,$A$2:$C$6,3,0))
```

That is the alternative formula to place in F2 and copy down.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula:

```
=IF(D2<>"NULL",VLOOKUP(D2,A2:C6,3,FALSE),"Value is NULL")
```

Here is the working example:

[image]

Put formula in cell **`F2`** and drag it down.